# replace wrong input from input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I'm trying to replace wrong input form input field. Is this any way to made this code work?

```
<span class="input-bet">
  <input type="text" placeholder="0" data-required="true" maxlength='6'/>
</span>

$('.input-bet > input').on('input propertychange paste', function(e) {
 var youreg = /^[ю]+/gi;
 for (var i = 0;i<this.value.length;i++){
     if(this.value[i].match(youreg)){
         this.value[i] = this.value[i].replace(youreg, '.');
     }
 }
```

if someone need - here is working solution 
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DronSKM/pmj0w64k/1/)

Comment: can you put your html here ?

Comment: you must use change instead of propertychange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign to individual characters in the text input element's value. You can, however, *replace* the value. Your script can be changed to this:

```
$('.input-bet > input').on('input propertychange paste', function(e) {
 var youreg = /ю/gi;
 for (var i=0; i<this.value.length; i++){
     if (this.value[i].match(youreg)) {
         this.value = this.value.replace(youreg, '.');
     }
 }});
```

But this is inefficient because it performs a regex `match` for every character. Instead you can replace the offending characters in one go using `replace()`:

```
$('.input-bet > input').on('input propertychange paste', function(e) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/ю/ig, '.');
});
```

Note that the `[]` in your pattern is not required if you are matching just a single character. If you want to match and replace multiple characters then you can use this pattern:

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/[a-zю]/ig, '.');
```

which for example will replace all characters from 'a' to 'z' as well as 'ю'.

Comment: i don't know how, but actually your first code is working in a right way. It's replace only 'ю' character form input. Thanks a lot) You can try it here https://jsfiddle.net/DronSKM/pmj0w64k/1/ i change 'ю' character to 'r '

Comment: @BogdanTushevskyi: I thought that I had explained how it works: replace the entire value, not individual characters. The first code sample is to show how your code could be fixed. The second code sample is to show a better way to do it. The second way is more efficient and is shorter, so I recommend that you use that.